# What language runs after I start a Konsole window, and what can it do?

Tags: linux, shell

1. How can I store the result of an an expression into a variable?

   ```
   echo "hello" > var1
   ```
2. Can I also do something like this?

   ```
   var1.substring(10,15);
   var1.replace('hello', '2');
   var1.indexof('hello')
   ```

*PS. I had tried Googling, but was not sucessful.*

Comment: It's not konsole that you script. It's the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @larsmans comments, `Konsole` is the terminal emulator, which in turn runs a shell.
On linux, this is typically `bash`, but it could be something else.

Find out what shell you're using, and print the man page.

```
echo $SHELL         # shows the full path to the shell
man ${SHELL##*/}    # use the rightmost part (typically bash, in linux)
```

For a general introduction, use the  [wikipedia entry on the unix shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) or the [GNU Bash refererence](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)

Some specific answers:

```
var1="hello"
echo ${var1:0:4}         # prints "hell"
echo ${var1/hello/2}     # prints "2" -- replace "hello" with "2"
```

And at the risk of showing off:

```
index_of() { (t=${1%%$2*} && echo ${#t}); }  # define function index_of
index_of "I say hello" hello
6
```

But this goes beyond simple shell programming.

Comment: Can you please also post how to do it on tcsh. It would be really helpful. Apparently, that is my console shell.

Comment: just the indexof should be fine the rest are very similar in both

Comment: You don't program in tcsh.  Seriously.  It's better than the original csh, but any serious shell programming is done in a descendant of the old unix Bourne shell.  That includes `bash`, `dash`, `ksh93` or `zsh`.  If you cannot change the default, you can still start any of the alternatives by typing their name.

Answer (score 1):

Konsole is bash basically. So its technically bash that you are looking for.

Suppose:

```
s="hello"
```

For `var1.substring(1,3);`

you would do:

```
$ echo ${s:1:2}
el
```

For `var1.replace('e', 'u');`

you can:

```
$ echo ${s/l/u} #replace only the first instance.
hullo
$ echo ${s//e/u} #this will replace all instances of e with u
```

For `var1.indexof('l')`

You can (I dont know of any bash-ish method but, anyway):

```
$ echo $(expr index hello l)
4
```

Comment: `index_of() { (t=${1%%$2*} && echo ${#t}); }` is a very shell-ish method.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` (the standard shell on linux) the syntax for storing the result of an expression in a variable is

```
VAR=$( EXPRESSION )
```

so, for example:

```
$ var=$(echo "hello")
$ echo $var
hello
```

For your second question: yes, these kind of things are possible using only the shell - but you're probably better of using a scripting language like python.

For what its worth: [Here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) is a document describing how to do string manipulations in bash.

As you can see, it's not exactly beautiful.

Comment: 'not exactly beautiful.' I must agree with that.  Functions help.